# C# HtmlAgilityPack Working On HtmlNodeCollection

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is html codes :

```
<div id="frmPnlProductGallery">
        <ul class="clearfix">
                <li>
                    <a data-index="0" class="productItem" href="javascript:void(0)" title="https://file.digi-kala.com/digikala/Image/Webstore/ProductPhoto/P_118274/Original/234942.jpg" rel="dk-gallery-item" data-imgurl="https://file.digi-kala.com/digikala/Image/Webstore/ProductPhoto/P_118274/Original/234942.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-index="1" class="productItem" href="javascript:void(0)" title="https://file.digi-kala.com/digikala/Image/Webstore/ProductPhoto/P_118274/Original/c9ebc3.jpg" rel="dk-gallery-item" data-imgurl="https://file.digi-kala.com/digikala/Image/Webstore/ProductPhoto/P_118274/Original/c9ebc3.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-index="2" class="productItem" href="javascript:void(0)" title="https://file.digi-kala.com/digikala/Image/Webstore/ProductPhoto/P_118274/Original/12199f.jpg" rel="dk-gallery-item" data-imgurl="https://file.digi-kala.com/digikala/Image/Webstore/ProductPhoto/P_118274/Original/12199f.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Now i want to grab three `title=` into a `List<string>`.
Here is the codes :

```
var lis = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='frmPnlProductGallery']//ul//li");
List<string> ls_images = new List<string>();
```

Now how can i grab those three titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **/a** to your xpath and select **title** attribute

```
List<string> ls_images = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
      .SelectNodes(@"div[@id='frmPnlProductGallery']/ul/li/a")
      .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("title", string.Empty))
      .ToList();
```

Comment: What is that string.Empty?

Comment: **string.Empty** (empty string i.e. **""**) will be returned if attribute **title** will not be found

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq here. For example

```
document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Where(_ => _.HasClass("productItem")).Select(_ => _.GetAttributeValue("title", ""));
```

This is the `HasClass` extension method:

```
public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
{
     var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
     var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
     return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
}
```